# Express api requests stop working after a while with MERN

Tags: reactjs, express, http, python-requests, mern

So I have a social media app that I previously made using MySQL express React js and Node. But I recently migrated the backend to mongoDb and now my express requests stop working after a while. When I comment out most of my requests and leave only a few the requests work. But when I uncomment all the requests, they work for a few seconds then they stop.

Here is how the backend is set up with one post request

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer")
require("dotenv").config();
const session = require("session")
const FileStore = require("express-file-store")
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UsersModel = require("./models/Users");
const PostsModel = require("./models/Posts")
const CommentsModel = require("./models/Comments")
const LikesModel = require("./models/Likes")
const StoriesModel = require("./models/Stories");
const RelationshipsModel = require("./models/Relationships");


const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/socialmedia?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false", 
// {useNewUrlParser: true});

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://saifkhadraoui656:2j446qaqKhrdQGgD@socialmedia.80hqtw3.mongodb.net/")


app.post("/register", async(req,res) => {

    const username = req.body.username;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const name = req.body.name;
    

    const user = new UsersModel({
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        name: name
    })
    await user.save();
    res.send("user registered")
})
```

And here is how I'm sending it from the front end

```
  async function registerUser(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    Axios.post("http://localhost:1337/register", {
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        name: name
      }).then((response) => {
          navigate("/")
      })
  }
```

All the requests were working previously with MySQL but now with mongoDb they sometimes work and sometimes don't.

Comment: You should `try ... catch` the user creation in `/register` and see if some exception is thrown.

Comment: @Ipizzinidev I tried that and nothing was being caught. It seems like the useEffect runs but when it gets to axios request it doesn't run it for some reason